# passing object through a setPropertyActionListener returning null

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In my application, when the user log in i need to send his information to a MenuManagedBean to identify which menu to show (I am trying the primefaces programmatic menu example) but when i attempt to do it the object sent to the managedBean via the setPropertyActionListener is always null and i can't figure out where is my fault.

This my jsf page code

```
                 <h:form class="contact-us">
            <h1 style="font-family: 'Segoe UI light'">GED</h1>
            <div style="margin-left: 33%">

                <br></br> <br></br>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-left: 25%">
                <p:inputText id="login" placeholder="login ..." required="true"
                    requiredMessage="Login obligatoire" value="#{persMb.personnel.login}">
                    <p:message for="login" display="text" />
                </p:inputText>
                <p:inputText type="password" id="password"
                    placeholder="mot de passe ..." required="true"
                    requiredMessage="Mot de passe obligatoire" value="#{persMb.personnel.motDePasse}">
                    <p:message for="password" display="text" />
                </p:inputText>
                <br /> <br />
            </div>
            <p:commandButton styleClass="font-custom"
                value="Connexion" ajax="false" action="#{persMb.checkValidUser}" process="@this">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{menuMb.role}"
                            value="#{persMb.personnel.role}"  />
                </p:commandButton>

        </h:form>
```

This my MenuBean Code

```
                private MenuModel model;
private Personnel personnel = new Personnel();
private Role role= new Role();
    private PersonnelDao pDao = new PersonnelDao();
public MenuMb() {
System.out.println(" role ="+role.getIdRole()); 
if(role.getIdRole()==1)
{
    model = new DefaultMenuModel();
DefaultSubMenu firstSubmenu = new DefaultSubMenu("Services");
DefaultMenuItem item = new DefaultMenuItem("Internes");
item.setUrl("http://localhost:8080/GED/Service/servicesinter.xhtml");
firstSubmenu.addElement(item);
item = new DefaultMenuItem("Externes");
item.setUrl("http://localhost:8080/GED/Service/serviceexter.xhtml");
firstSubmenu.addElement(item);
model.addElement(firstSubmenu);
DefaultSubMenu secondSubmenu = new DefaultSubMenu("Personnels");
item = new DefaultMenuItem("Personnels");
item.setUrl("http://localhost:8080/GED/Personnel/personnel.xhtml");
secondSubmenu.addElement(item);
model.addElement(secondSubmenu);
DefaultSubMenu thirdSubmenu = new DefaultSubMenu("Etablissements");
item = new DefaultMenuItem("Etablissements");
item.setUrl("http://localhost:8080/GED/Personnel/personnel.xhtml");
thirdSubmenu.addElement(item);
model.addElement(thirdSubmenu);
DefaultSubMenu fourthSubmenu = new DefaultSubMenu("Courriers");
item = new DefaultMenuItem("Arrivés");
item.setUrl("#");
fourthSubmenu.addElement(item);
item = new DefaultMenuItem("Départs");
item.setUrl("#");
fourthSubmenu.addElement(item);
model.addElement(fourthSubmenu);
DefaultSubMenu fifthSubmenu = new DefaultSubMenu("Paramétrage");
item = new DefaultMenuItem("Paramétrage");
item.setUrl("#");
fifthSubmenu.addElement(item);
model.addElement(fifthSubmenu);
}
```

I am using jsf2.2.

Comment: Have you ensured the role is not null in principle ?

Comment: it's passed as a null value from the jsf page, i even tried to pass personnel object but in persMb it works and in menuMb it's null

Comment: Getters/Setters are available in `menuMB`?

Comment: yes i generated the getters and setters in the menuMb `private Role role= new Role();                                                public Role getRole() {return role;}
public void setRole(Role role) {this.role = role;}`